# JPanels except the first not drawn

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The following code supposed to read a file containing a set of molecular structures, then add a bunch of JPanels (equal to the number of molecules) and create a molecule on each panel. I get the right no of panels at the runtime. However only the first molecule is drawn on the first panel?

Comment: The code for MolViewer might be necessary also.

Comment: MolViewer paints the JPanel with a molecule. When I manually add a bunch of MolViewer Panels like molViewer1 = new MolViewer(); molViewer2 = new MolViewer(); it worked fine. My guess is it has to do with referencing panels. In a related note is it possible to generate a set of JPanels like Jpanel1, JPanel2 within a loop with an index.

Comment: @lochi: that doesn't tell us much. For instance for all we know you've got a static variable on MolViewer that mucks up your ability to show multiple molecules. The code might help us figure this out. But... up to you.

Comment: Also, have you added debug statements to your code?

Comment: image = new BufferedImage(this.getPreferredSize().width, this.getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drawMolViewPanel()` function seems a little overengineered. For one, the `panes` list seems to be mostly temporary (you add objects to it, then from that list, add them to the `MolTable`'s own panel collection; I don't think you need it). If I understand the function correctly, this does the same thing and makes more sense to me:

```
public void drawMolViewPanel(String sdf) throws FileNotFoundException, CDKException
{
    ReadSDF(sdf);
    this.removeAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.fragments.size(); i++)
    {    
        MolViewer mv = new MolViewer();
        mv.setMolecule((Molecule)this.fragments.get(i));
        this.add(mv);
    }

    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

I'm not entirely sure that's your issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes this should work. The problem was with part of the MolViewer. image = new BufferedImage(this.getPreferredSize().width, this.getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Is ReadSDF working properly? Without knowing much more, it might be possible that fragments is not being initialised properly, so when you go to access the elements it doesn't work properly, an exception is thrown which is caught and ignored by something higher up.

Cory Larson's code seems like it should work to me. It is logically the same.

I notice where you override 'paintComponent' in MolViewer, you call super.paintComponents(g) (a method of Container) rather than paintComponent (the method of JComponent). I haven't done enough with graphics in swing, to know if this is correct though, so feel free to ignore this.

Also, a (very) small thing: You're using LinkedLists for random access. ArrayList would be a better implementation in general if you're accessing with an index number.

Comment: image = new BufferedImage(this.getPreferredSize().width, this.getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); fixed the problem